# Where is it mentioned the Accelerator's Vector Transformation works on all 11 dimensions?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index

The wiki says this about Accelerator's Vector Transformation:

> It is said to even be able to reflect teleportation vectors in the 11th dimension, though a strange phenomenon would occur in the 3-dimensional world, so thus people could not teleport harmful objects into his body, as most Teleporters would do in a battle.

However, no source is cited. I've searched the entire light novel for it, and haven't found where "It is said".

Is their claim true? Where is that stated in the series?

Comment: Probably a good place to start searching: http://forums.animesuki.com/archive/index.php/t-68255-p-18.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *To Aru Majutsu no Index* light novel volume 6, page 57, it is explained how teleporters use the 11th dimension to move objects:

> [...] Though the phrase “to teleport within space” sounded simple, the theory behind it was to get away from the three dimensions, find her position in the eleventh dimension, and then calculate the vectors to teleport. [...]

In volume 20, page 107, it is specifically explained that:

> When he reflected teleportation powers, a strange phenomenon occurred in the 3
>   dimensional world, [...]